How can I make an Amiibo from an NFC card?
For Christmas, I got an NFC reader/writer for my PC, and nearly a hundred NFC cards. I found this Amiibo Database on GitHub, but I found out the NFC files alone aren't enough for my New Nintendo 3DS XL to recognize it. How can I get an NFC card to work like an Amiibo?
The app I'm using to write information into my card is NFC Tools by Wakdev.

What model of 3DS do you use? You'll need a separate reading device if it's a 3DS (XL) or 2DS. You also need NTAG215 type NFC tags, no others will do AFAIK.

I have a NEW 3DS XL, and reads my Amiibos well. I was not aware about the different tag types, unfortunately.

@Pilzkopf I forgot to at you. (I wish the site would recommend doing it)

Ahh! I do have NTAG215!!! I didn't recognize them at first, but I took a good look at them and now I know what they are. I have what I need.

Not all NFC writing apps support what you are going for (NFC Tools likely included) so you'd be wise to use one made specifically for the job. I'd suggest checking out a guide online.
